# Interactive Jupyter notebook not being displayed on Github

Tags: python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook, plotly, choropleth

```
fig = px.choropleth(c_lat_grp, locations="Country", locationmode='country names',
                color="Cases", hover_name="Country", 
                color_continuous_scale="Emrld", title='COVID-19')

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Here is my python3 code which displays a world map, displays details of maps when you hover around it using the chloropleth library. It is running perfectly fine in my Jupyter notebook but when I am uploading it to Github it is not showing me any map. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to [GitHub Help doc](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github):

> When you add Jupyter Notebook or IPython Notebook files with a .ipynb extension on GitHub, they will render as static HTML files in your repository.
>
> The interactive features of the notebook, such as custom JavaScript
>   plots, will not work in your repository on GitHub.
>
> To view your Jupyter notebook with JavaScript content rendered or to share your notebook files with others you can use nbviewer.

Therefore, you can:

1. go to [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)
2. enter the location of a Jupyter Notebook to have it rendered
3. push `Go!` button

Enjoy your interactive map!

Comment: Please, accept my asnwer if it solves your problem. Thanks.